# How to monitor a windows log file in real time?

Tags: windows, monitoring, log-files, realtime

On windows how can I easily *monitor* a log file and see updates to the file in *real time*?

Basically, same functionality like `tail -f log_file` on Unix systems

**Platform**: Windows XP/2003/2008 server

**[Update]** this is quite handy for a quick monitoring(thanks to Ckarras's [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1845/how-to-monitor-a-log-file-in-real-time/64129#64129))

Quick screen shot of PowerShell `type -wait` (type is an alias for `get-content`)
[image]

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Sung, Do you need readonly or editable?

Comment: Why was this question marked off-topic?!?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel Folks who closed marked it as "they tend to become obsolete quickly." It's a very old question so probably so.

Comment: @dance2die — It is very frustrating to search for answers to real tech questions that I have only to find the question that could have possibly answered my question was closed by the pendants on the site for some arcane reason. It has me leaving the site with a negative feeling about the sites. And I say this as a former moderator on one of StackExchange sites. #justsaying

Comment: @MikeSchinkel This question does have potential should I had kept it up to date. Hopefully folks w/ enough reps can reopen and reply with latest ways

Comment: How is this question even remotely off-topic?! Monitoring windows log files, sounds a lot like the first two bullet points of "on-topic" items listed here https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've been using [BareTailPro](http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretailpro/index.php) for awhile, and have been very pleased.  It hasn't been updated in awhile, but it still meets my needs.  There's also a free version.

Here's some of the features:

- View files of any size (> 2GB)
- Configurable highlighting
- Monitor multiple files simultaneously
- High-performance search algorithm
- Regular expression text search
- Filter tail mode (include or exclude lines)

Comment: This is what (BareTail Free version) I settled with for now.  Thanks Rob

Comment: This is much slow for big files with long lines and the last update is from 2006 (12 years ago). The best program is pointed on this other answer [Log viewer on Windows](https://superuser.com/a/315381/458103). The program [glogg](http://glogg.bonnefon.org/description.html) despite being simpler than this, handles big files with much better performance, was updated just last year, is open source (https://github.com/nickbnf/glogg) and has support to Windows, Linux and Max OSX.

Answer (score 41):

There's also an equivalent to "tail -f" under Windows, if you have PowerShell installed:

```
type -wait
```

Comment: Wow. this is quite awesome. I had no idea about that "-wait" option for "Get-Content".  Thanks ckarras.  I have also updated question with the screenshot.

Comment: Have an upvote for giving an answer that shows you can do this right out of the box if you know how to use OS and that you don't need to install 3rd party tools.

Comment: For those of us unfamiliar with `tail -f`, what does `type -wait` do?

Comment: It continuously watches the file for appended data and writes the new content to the console

Comment: wait what is the sample use

Comment: And it has to be emphasized that it must be **PowerShell!!!** Because it also works in ordinary command line and simply outputs content of a file without waiting.

Answer (score 27):

I use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/) as my default text editor on all my systems, and it has the nice bonus of having this built-in - just go Plugins -> Document Monitor -> Start to monitor. You can also use File -> Reload from disk to manually reload it.

Comment: +1 Wow, I have been using Notepad++ for awhile but didn't know about this functionality. thanks.

Comment: does this still exist, I don't see it in version 5.9.8 that I just downloaded.

Comment: @Scott can be downloaded as a plugin http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/DocMonitor/

Comment: +1 from me too. I love Notepad++ but didn't even think of looking for a plugin. Bye bye BareTail.

Answer (score 23):

You don't mention which platform you're using, but on Unix-like systems the `tail` command does this:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

In fact there are implementations of `tail` for Windows also (eg. [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)).

Answer (score 22):

Actually, [**Log-Expert**](https://github.com/zarunbal/LogExpert) does what you want, plus a lot of nice feature

[image: Features for Log-Exprt]

Comment: yeah, this solution rocks. Better than notepad++, which only updates every 3 seconds, and is a bit flaky.

Comment: Plus its free :)

Comment: @VonC, Any disclaimers?

Comment: @Pacerier none that I can think of. But that was 6 years ago.

Comment: +1 to this answer. LogExpert is by far the best free log monitoring tool. Much better than Baretail (which doesn't even have search in free version).

Comment: wow, i didnt knew this exists. ive been kicking my ass on the tail -f command [+1]

Answer (score 21):

If windows is your thing you could try [Tail for Win32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tailforwin32).

edit: Another alternative I just found is [TailXP](http://infiero.com/tailxp/index.html). It's free, but not opensource. Looks ok from the description but I haven't tried it.

Comment: The advanced features feel a little buggy but for simply tailing the file, it's perfect.

Comment: Because of "tail" stuff people were mentioning, I found something called "BareTail" - http://www.baremetalsoft.com/baretail/  So far it seems to be doing what I wanted.  But I am open for more suggestions.

Comment: That one looks nice to know about too.

Answer (score 5):

I have had good luck with the windows program mtail.  It does a very nice job of monitoring an active log.  You can configure quite a few options but in general I have found the defaults work very well.

[mtail](http://ophilipp.free.fr/op_tail.htm)

Comment: Great!  I didn't get to run into this one.

Answer (score 4):

Like `tail -f file.log`?

Comment: But doesn't this mean I have to be running the command constantly?

Comment: No, the tail command will wait after printing the last line, and when the file is updated/appended it will print the new line(s) and wait again. Instead of plain tail you might try http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/.

Comment: He also said for the Windows OS.

Comment: Not when I answered, he hadn't.

Answer (score 3):

"tail -f logname"?

Comment: He edited his post to say it's for Windows OS only.

Comment: There are plenty of versions of tail for Windows, including in cygwin.

Answer (score 3):

I love the Kiwi Log Viewer.  They were just bought out by Solarwinds -- I assume the product is still for sale (or maybe they're giving it away for free now?  They're giving away a few other Kiwi products).

Comment: Would you post link to Kiwi Log Viewer?
I am not sure if this one I found is the one you are referring to: http://www.kiwisyslog.com/kiwi-log-viewer-overview/

Comment: Yeah, that's the one -- kiwisyslog.com

Answer (score 2):

If you install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) on your Windows machine, you can run `tail`

Comment: Hmm. Cygwin. I haven't played around with that for years...

Answer (score 2):

I typically do this with [TextPad](http://textpad.com).  It has the option to monitor that a file has been modified.  It is an option to either automatically update the window or to prompt you whether or not you want to reload the file.

Comment: It looks like TextPad has a the same capability as NotePad++'s Document Monitor plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you're using eclipse there's a fully sick plugin called Log Watcher

http://graysky.sourceforge.net/

It supports multiple files, plus color highlighting.